# hibernate criteria. self join for denormalized table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hello all and sorry for my English =)
I works with Hibernate using criteria API. Everything was fine, but I have several denormalized tables with data for reports, and I faced some troubles.
For one of that tables I created @Entity class for mapping like

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "table")
public class Report {

    @Id
    Integer id;

    Integer product_id;

    Integer warehouse_id;

    String some_data;

}
```

with simple queries all works fine. But I need to make queries like pivot table or self join etc.
for example

```
select 
    t1.product_id, 
    t2.warehouse_id
from repost t1
    join report t2 
    on  t1.product_id = t2.product_id 
        and t1.warehoise_id = ?
where t1.some_data in (?)
```

Such query does not contain logical dependencies between entities like *Primary_Key - Foreign_Key* and can return custom object data (it can be Map<>, List<>, Pair<>, Long...)

Is it possible to make query like this without using HQL?

Thanks

**ADDED**
As I was understood it's not possible using HQL too

Comment: If you wouldn't use `HQL query`, you can try with native sql query. See [doc here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I can use and HQL, and JDBC if it would be necessary, but I want to avoid it.

Comment: You need a native query in this case, `HQL` need all the joins market with `@XXXtoXXX` like annotations.

Comment: I found out that I can make JOIN using HQL, but only INNER join...
As result... I can use only native SQL in Hibernate or JDBC. 
Thanks all!